# Insert file image from database mysql to excel

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, excel

PHP for the master here I have a little problem to capture the image data input from php adn html database to excel.

here I use a table as its media html:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=tes.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td> Name </ td>
<td> Address </ td>
<td> <img src='foto_saya.jpg' width='100px' height='100px'>> </ td>
</ tr>
</ table>
```

I want to ask is on the output column in excel foto_saya image size is 100x100
but that came out diexcel image file with its original size,
then I already use the `style = "width: 100px; height: 100px"`
still it does not affect anything,
Maybe someone can help me this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: I do not wuite understant the question

Comment: please check again my question which I fix.

Comment: You realise that you're not actually writing an Excel file... you're writing an HTML file with an extension of .xls.... PHP doesn't automagically convert HTML markup to a real Excel file. Although MS Excel is remarkably forgiving when somebody loads that file, it isn't perfect. Don't try to force exactness using this method. Why not consider writing a real Excel file instead?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure the size of an image for display in Excel using the style attribute.

If you want the image to appear a specific size without using style rules, you would need to resize it using the GD image library.

This would look something like this:

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'test.png';

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = 100; // pixels
$new_height = 100; // pixels

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagepng($image_p, 'test-resized.png');
?>
```

Then you will want to use the resized image for your HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> Name </ td>
<td> Address </ td>
<td> <img src='test-resized.png' width='100px' height='100px'>> </ td>
</ tr>
</ table>
```